# How can I create the number of custom post views

Tags: views

I am creating a forum plugin and need to count how many people have seen a certain topic (post_type custom), ideally would be to create a new table or there is a form directly with wordpress.

Comment: What had you tried? What specific challenges you encountered?

Answer (score 0):

add this in your functions.php

```
function getPostViews($postID){
    $count_key = 'post_views_count';
    $count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
    if($count==''){
        delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
        add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
        return "0 View";
    }
    return $count;
}
function setPostViews($postID) {
    $count_key = 'post_views_count';
    $count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
    if($count==''){
        $count = 0;
        delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
        add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
    }else{
        $count++;
        update_post_meta($postID, $count_key, $count);
    }
}
```

Comment: hmm..this wont work if cache is enabled.